# VideoView CustomControllers Visibility

Tags: android, android-layout, custom-controls, android-videoview

I have created custom controllers with seekbar on videoview. These controllers are in a linearlayout and works fine. Now I want to set visibility of this custom controller layout like any other android player. Like when i starts the video it appears for 7 second then disappears and when user touches the video it appears and remain for 7 secs and touches again it disappears. My code is

```
myMusicView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                try {
                    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 700){
                        return false;
                    }
                    mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    if(isShowing){
                        musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        isShowing=false;
                    }else{
                        musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        HideLayout();
                        isShowing=true;
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }



                return false;
            }
        });

private void HideLayout() {

    try {
        musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         final Handler handler = new Handler();
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }, 7000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
1) First add this code as mention in above answer
private void loadTimer(){
try{
musicControlBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000){

    @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
             //this hide your layout when reach at 7 sec
            musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();

}catch(Exception e){}
}
2) Try onClickListener at VideoView in onClick() repeat your above code

                    if(isShowing){
                        musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        isShowing=false;
                    }else{

                        if(countDownTimer!=null){
                          countDownTimer.cancel();
                         loadTimer();//start timer
                         }
                        musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        isShowing=true;
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a Handler, I recommend using a CountDownTimer.

Declare a CountDownTimer variable global to the class as:

```
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
```

Make the following changes to your HideLayout() function:

```
try{
musicControlBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(7000, 1000){

    @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

            musicControllBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }.start();

}catch(Exception e){}
```

Also, replace your code

```
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 700){
                            return false;
}
```

with

```
countDownTimer.cancel();
```